# I reinstalled GRUB and now one Windows loader's been removed

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

My GRUB2 was removed after installing Windows 10.

I'm supposed to have 3 OS (yes I know they're too much but I need them all): Windows 10 64 bits, Windows 10 32 bits and Ubuntu.

So after finally being able of installing GRUB2 back using boot-repair one of my Windows 10 loaders is gone (32 bits one). I can only access Ubuntu and W10 64 bits from GRUB2.

Can anyone tell me please how to get that Windows back without messing GRUB2 again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please append the output of the commands `df` and `sudo fdisk -l` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it's not the answer, I can't comment yet.

I'm not that grub2 expert, but if it recovers the windows 64, there should be a way to recover the 32bits also.

For your next atemp on doing this mix of three systems I would recomend installing both windows, make sure both of them work, and then install ubuntu grub2 INSIDE the disk, NOT on MBR. This will not break the BCD of any windows installed previusly. Other way of course, it's using more than one disk, each with the BCD or grub2 installed on MBR.

Comment: _“Sorry if it's not the answer, I can't comment yet.”_ Please don’t include useless text in your answers. IMHO, this could be a valid answer, although OP is probably looking for a solution without the need for reinstalling.

Comment: @Melebius  thanks for comment, I include that useless text because I don't have the 50 points needed for comment questions yet. If you think this can be an answer, please vote my answer so I level up :D